# Open a new tab from a tab and select the new one

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm interested how I can open a tab from a already opened tab. For example I would like to open the new tab and automatically make it active.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tabs");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250, Color.WHITE);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Tab tab = new Tab();
            tab.setText("Tab" + i);
            HBox hbox = new HBox(new Button("Open new tab"));
            hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Tab" + i));
            hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            tab.setContent(hbox);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        }

        borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab first when open new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360079/how-to-open-a-new-tab-first-when-open-new-tab)

Comment: what exactly is the problem and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but I believe you want something like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tabs");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250, Color.WHITE);

        final TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Tab tab = new Tab();
            tab.setText("Tab" + i);
            Button btn = new Button("Open new tab");
            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    int j = tabPane.getTabs().size();
                    Tab tab = new Tab();
                    tab.setText("Tab" + j);
                    Label newTabLabel = new Label("The new and Awesome selected:");
                    HBox hbox = new HBox(newTabLabel);
                    hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Tab" + j));
                    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    tab.setContent(hbox);
                    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
                    tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(j);
                }
            });
            HBox hbox = new HBox(btn);
            hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Tab" + i));
            hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            tab.setContent(hbox);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        }

        borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```